# KnockJS and JQuery Tutorial assitance needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/into-the-ring-with-knockout-js/

I've worked to Round 2 – Creating a View, using the code as published on the site, I'm returned an error by FF FB 1.7.3

> Error: missing ) in parenthetical
>   Source File: http://testing:8888/knockout/js/behavior.js
>   Line: 7, Column: 3
>   Source Code:
>     }; ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

**Behavior**

```
(function ($) { var model = [{  name: "John",  address: "1, a road, a town, a county, a postcode",  tel: "1234567890",  site: "www.aurl.com", pic: "/i/john.jpg",  deleteMe: function () { viewModel.people.remove(this); }
}, {  name: "Jane",  address: "2, a street, a city, a county, a postcode",  tel: "1234567890",  site: "www.aurl.com",  pic: "/i/jane.jpg",  deleteMe: function () { viewModel.people.remove(this); }
}, {  name: "Fred",  address: "3, an avenue, a village, a county, a postcode",  tel: "1234567890",  site: "www.aurl.com",  pic: "/i/fred.jpg",  deleteMe: function () { viewModel.people.remove(this); }
}, {  name: "Freda",  address: "4, a street, a suburb, a county, a postcode",  tel: "1234567890",  site: "www.aurl.com",  pic: "/i/jane.jpg",  deleteMe: function () { viewModel.people.remove(this); }
}], viewModel = { people: ko.observableArray(model),
} }; ko.applyBindings(viewModel); })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code on the tutorial is flawed.  The behaviors.js code has an additional bracket between viewModel and ko.applyBindings.  It looks like this:

> viewModel = { people: ko.observableArray(model),
>   **}** }; ko.applyBindings...

It needs to look like this:

> viewModel = { people: ko.observableArray(model),
>   }; ko.applyBindings...

I didn't like several things about this sample.  Here is my version, slightly modified:

```
(function ($) { 
    var model, viewModel;
    model = [
        {
           name:"John",
           address:"1, a road, a town, a county, a postcode",
           tel:"1234567890",
           site:"www.aurl.com",
           pic:"/img/john.jpg",
           deleteMe:function ()   {
              viewModel.people.remove(this);
           }
        },
        {
           name:"Jane",
           address:"2, a street, a city, a county, a postcode",
           tel:"1234567890",
           site:"www.aurl.com",
           pic:"/img/jane.jpg",
           deleteMe:function ()   {
              viewModel.people.remove(this);
           }
        },
        {
           name:"Fred",
           address:"3, an avenue, a village, a county, a postcode",
           tel:"1234567890",
           site:"www.aurl.com",
           pic:"/img/fred.jpg",
           deleteMe:function ()   {
              viewModel.people.remove(this);
           }
        },
        {
           name:"Freda",
           address:"4, a street, a suburb, a county, a postcode",
           tel:"1234567890",
           site:"www.aurl.com",
           pic:"/img/jane.jpg",
           deleteMe:function ()   {
              viewModel.people.remove(this);
           }
        }
    ];
    viewModel = {
        people: ko.observableArray(model)  
    } ; 
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);  
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks, could you lend your wisdom on debugging, as nothing was returned to the error console or alerted?

Comment: This is still not working for you?  Do you have all the appropriate js files?

Comment: It's working, but was wondering if you lend your debugging insight, or was this something your already skilled with.

Comment: Absolutely.  Let me know what you need.

Comment: Firebug and the error console returned nothing. So if you would explain how to track down errors in Knockout?

Comment: That's a broad subject.  I doubt you are getting errors IN knockout (although possible).  You may not be using it correctly though.  Your best bet is to post specific questions on SO related to specific errors.  In general, console, firebug, alerts, etc, are all your friends.  If you get nothing, you may have a syntax error.  Try using jslint or another syntax checker.